# Using the input from updateSelectInput

Tags: r, shiny

My problem is when selecting data using the input from "updateSelectInput".

input$State and input$Company returns no values to my "data selection" function, input$Transport that is not an "update" works fine.

How I call an input when using "updateSelectInput"? Does it work in the same way as "selectInput"?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the data I created to simplify the problem:

```
    Company<- paste('company',1:95)
    State<- paste('state',1:20)
    Transport<-c('inter long','nacional long','nacional short','inter short')
    variable1<- sample(0:10,380,replace=T)
    variable2<- sample(0:10,380,replace=T)
    variable3<- sample(0:10,380,replace=T)
    variable4<- sample(0:10,380,replace=T)

    mydata<- data.frame(Company,State,Transport,variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4)
```

ui.R

```
    shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('Passengers Data'),
    sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Transport", "Select a Transport", choices = levels(mydata$Transport), selected = levels(mydata$Transport)[1]
    ),
   selectInput("State", "Select a State", choices = sort(levels(mydata$State)),selected = sort(levels(mydata$State)[1])),
    tags$hr(),
    checkboxGroupInput("Company", "Select Company", choices = mydata$Company[mydata$State ==sort(mydata$State )[1] & mydata$Transport==sort(mydata$Transport)[1]]),



    width = 3

    ),
    mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("plot1"),width = 9
    )
    ))
```

server.R

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(googleVis)
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    observe({
    Transport2<- input$Transport
    updateSelectInput(session, "State", choices = sort(levels(factor(mydata$State[mydata$Transport == Transport2]))),selected = sort(levels(factor(mydata$State[mydata$Transport == Transport2])))[1])
    })

    observe({
    Transport2<- input$Transport
    State2 <- input$State

    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "Company", choices = sort(levels(factor(mydata$Company[mydata$State == State2 & mydata$Transport == Transport2]))),selected=sort(levels(factor(mydata$Company[mydata$State == State2 & mydata$Transport == Transport2])))[1:5])
    })


    selectedData<-reactive({
    subset(mydata, mydata$Transport==input$Transport & mydata$State==input$State & mydata$Company==input$Company
    )
    })  




    output$plot1 <- renderGvis({

    gvisBarChart(selectedData(), xvar="Company", yvar="variable1",
                         options=list(legend='none', width=750, height=425,title="Resultado geral",
                                      titleTextStyle="{color:'black',fontName:'Courier',fontSize:16}",
                                      bar="{groupWidth:'70%'}"))



    })

    })
```

Comment: Without at least some sample data for `dados` that means that all this code isn't runnable so the problem isn't reproducible. It's much easier to help you find solutions when you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I edited the question and I hope it is now clearer @MrFlick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there's a bug in this line:

```
subset(mydata, mydata$Transport==input$Transport & mydata$State==input$State & mydata$Company==input$Company
```

Specifically the last clause:

```
mydata$Company==input$Company
```

should be replaced with

```
mydata$Company %in% input$Company
```

since input$Company can have multiple values.

---

Also, the `selected` values you're passing to updateSelectInput are sometimes `c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)` which Shiny doesn't understand (it causes a JavaScript error in the browser). You should call `na.omit` on the selection before you give it to updateSelectInput. (If this makes things even worse, install the latest version of `RJSONIO` from CRAN--it used to have a bug with empty vectors in lists.)

---

Thirdly, I'd recommend adding this code to the top of your `renderGvis` expression:

```
validate(
  need(nrow(selectedData()) > 0, "No data")
)
```

It will make it easier to detect when there are no rows in your data (rather than a blank graph which could be the result of an error or something).